# How to set WAN side buffers for WRT54GL running Tomato Firmware

Tags: networking, router, tomato, wrt54g

I've recently set up a machine running m0n0wall to try and fight buffer bloat and do some traffic shaping. It was more convenient (geographically speaking) to connect the cable modem directly to my old WRT54GL, then pass everything to the m0n0wall machine and have that do the real routing work.

It took a bit of work, but it's working pretty well. I have a cable connection. I have m0n0wall set up to utilize only 90% of the specified speed of my subscription, which is fine. But I've noticed that at certain times of the day (possibly when my true bandwidth drops below that 90%), there's more latency if the connection is used heavily, and traffic shaping doesn't seem to work as well.

I suspect this is caused by the buffers on the WRT54GL still being unnecessarily large. If the connection is working as expected, they won't get filled, but in times of reduced bandwidth they would.

`Does anyone know the command I need to execute, on the WRT54GL running Tomato Firmware, to reduce the buffers on the WAN interface to the minimum size possible?`